# How to fast identify contiguous range of 1’s(Index) in huge binary data?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

Could anyone suggest faster algorithm to identify continuous range of 1's in large binary data ?

Is traversing the data is the only solution? Traversing will give `O(n)` in worst case which I really don't want.

Does anyone can suggest faster algorithm?

As shown in below fig. I need to find the index 4000 which is start position of continuous range of 1's

```
index 0
|
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111100000
```

Comment: If something was faster than O(n) it would not look at some bits and those bits might be 1's.  Pack the bits 32 to an int, and you can skip 0's 32 at a time.

Comment: @brianbeuning it would still be O(n), just with a lower constant factor

Comment: It needs to stop in the first range or create a map? And, just two 'ones' can still be called a range?

Comment: Checking big lumps at a time would help, but ultimatly, the binary data will be either 0 or 1, and to check which it is, you need to check each lump [unless there is some external information available to tell you what is more likely, etc]

Comment: Of course there are lots of cases where running 64 or 128 times faster is indeed quite a good performance boost. Also, with multiple processors, one could partition the work into several "large lumps".

Comment: @CapEnt     Yes, It should stop  once it find the first range.  Threshold is 3 for for continuous range.  i.e. at least 3 one's

Comment: So check if an intX_t is > 7, then "investigate", otherwise "move on".

Comment: Any more information about the problem? Size of the buffer? How many segments with ones are threre? What is there length? Where do you excpect the block of ones to appear?

Comment: @AK_  Data will be in 50-60 GB in size. This is  RNA data (Bioinformatics)

Comment: The worst case will always be O(n) because you can get a sequence with no 1s and you need to look at each bit to be sure it's not 1. You might be able to somewhat improve the average case though, depending on the distribution of your data.

Comment: At 50e9 bits, this is a lot of bits.  How many times is each one scanned?  What is the expected ratio of 0's to 1's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not think of anything that would not be O(n), since the data is always unsorted.

But, i can think of shortcuts, since you want a set of at least 3, and is binary data.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int seed = 3758096384; //11100000000000000000000000000000
    unsigned int testvar = 419307644; //00011000111111100010000001111100
    int result = 0;
    int continuous = 0;

    while (seed != 7 && (continuous == 1 || result == 0)) {
        if (seed == (testvar & seed)) {
            result |= seed;
            continuous = 1;
        } else
            continuous = 0;
        seed >>= 1;
    }
    // result = 16646144 or 00000000111111100000000000000000
    cout << result << endl;
    //the index, 8388608 or 00000000100000000000000000000000
    cout << (int)((result ^ (result >> 1)) & ~(result >> 1)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How it works:
It is a binary filter, it creates a mask of 3 bits, and continuous shift to left by 1 in every step of the loop.

So you have these numbers as filters:

```
3758096384 - 11100000000000000000000000000000
1879048192 - 01110000000000000000000000000000
939524096  - 00111000000000000000000000000000
...
14         - 00000000000000000000000000001110
7          - 00000000000000000000000000000111
```

Then it checks if the seed match with the result of a logical AND between the number tested and the seed itself (this filters all the numbers that don't match the filter).

If the seed and the AND match, it moves the seed to the result using a logical OR, and set a continuous to control the continuity of the sequence. The first time the result is not continuous, it breaks the loop.

In the end, you have the result and can calculate the index by:

```
1110
0111 SHIFT TO LEFT by 1 and XOR
1001
0111 NOT (SHIFT TO LEFT by 1) and AND
------------
1000
```

You will need to scan your 50gb data in 32bits chunks (easy to adapt to 64bits, or even do vectorization of it).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't avoid going through the entire data at least once (you have to *look* at everything at least!), but you can avoid going through it multiple times if you e.g. [run-length encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) the data.